# Why did I get rid of an error (reference to " " is ambiguous) just by removing using namespace std; in c++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I was writing a recursive function (in C++) and instead of putting the arrays as parameters of function I made them global.

When i used those global arrays in my recursive function I got this following error:

```
"error: reference to "(name of array)" is ambiguous"
```

My Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define int long long int

int left[100],rit[100],col[100],ans=0; // Global arrays
char a[10][10];

int ways(int x,int res[][100])  // recursive function
{
  if(x==9){ans++;}
  for(int y=1;y<=8;y++)
  {
    if(res[x][y])continue;
    if(col[y] || left[x+y] || rit[y-x+8])continue;     //"error: reference to 'left' is ambiguous"
    col[y]=left[x+y]=rit[y-x+8]=1;
    ways(x+1,res);
    col[y]=left[x+y]=rit[y-x+8]=0;
  }
  return ans;
}

int32_t main()
{
  int res[100][100]={0};
  for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
  {
    for(int j=1;j<=8;j++)
    {
       cin>>a[i][j];
      if(a[i][j]=='*'){res[i][j]=1;}
    }
  }
  cout<<ways(1,res);

}
```

Surprisingly, I got rid of this error message when I removed `using namespace std;` 
   and my code compiled successfully with no error message.

My successfully compiled code:

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>

#define int long long int

int left[100],rit[100],col[100],ans=0;
char a[10][10];

int ways(int x,int res[][100])
{
  if(x==9){ans++;}
  for(int y=1;y<=8;y++)
  {
    if(res[x][y])continue;
    if(col[y] || left[x+y] || rit[y-x+8])continue;
    col[y]=left[x+y]=rit[y-x+8]=1;
    ways(x+1,res);
    col[y]=left[x+y]=rit[y-x+8]=0;
  }
  return ans;
}

int32_t main()
{
  int res[100][100]={0};
  for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
  {
    for(int j=1;j<=8;j++)
    {
       std::cin>>a[i][j];
      if(a[i][j]=='*'){res[i][j]=1;}
    }
  }
  std::cout<<ways(1,res); 

}
```

**My Question is:**
why did I get rid of this error by just simply removing `using namespace std;`?

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>  using namespace std;` That's TWO problems right here. Never use either line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because **left** is the manipulator defined in C++ under namespace std.As,you are using it in your program as a global variable,it causes ambiguity.
If you rename **left** to lef(or any other name that is not keyword or manipulator)in your program,your program works perfectly.

Check this link to know about **left** manipulator:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/left

Hope it helps!!

Comment: `left is the keyword` is not a keyword. Keywords as `for`, `while`, `class`, `if`, …

Answer (score 3):

That's one of the reasons why you should not use `using namespace std`

The complete error is:

```
  error: reference to ‘left’ is ambiguous
  note: candidates are: ‘std::ios_base& std::left(std::ios_base&)’
      left(ios_base& __base)
      ^~~~
   …
  int left [100]
  int left[100],rit[100],col[100],ans=0; // Global arrays
      ^~~~
```

Because of  `using namespace std` the compiler is not able to know if you mean `std::left(std::ios_base&)` or `int left[100]`. Without `using namespace std` it is not `ambiguous` anymore, because then `std::left(std::ios_base&)` has to be referenced with the `std::` before it.

Comment: "Never write `using namespace`" is a pretty decent rule of thumb.